# How can I have in appSettings entries with key, value and type?

Tags: c#, .net, types, configuration

I have something like this in a .Net WebService in my appSettings section:

```
<setting key="MaxLoginAttempts" value="3" />
<setting key="BeginDate" value="18-3-2019" />
<setting key="UserName" value="hello" />
```

I want to be able to add new config in execution time so it finish like this:

```
<setting key="MaxLoginAttempts" value="3" type="int"/>
<setting key="BeginDate" value="18-3-2019" type="datetime"/>
<setting key="UserName" value="hello" type="string"/>
```

So I can recover and use them to create instances of those types with reflection.

Is there any way to code this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show example of how you want to use them?

Comment: You know the key you search so why you don't parse the value in the rigth type when you get it ?